# Create index in MongoDB 3.2 to avoid duplicated documents/rows

Tags: java, mongodb, indexing, duplicates, crud

I'm using MongoDB 3.2 and want to avoid the duplicates in my collection. In order to do that I use `createIndex()` method (I tried different variants, none of them doesn't work):

```java
dbColl.createIndex(new Document("guid", 1));
dbColl.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("guid", 1));
dbColl.createIndex(new Document("guid.content", 1));
dbColl.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("guid.content", 1));
```

Then I try to execute data insert with:

```java
itemsArr.forEach(
    item -> dbColl.insertOne(Document.parse(item.toString()))
);
```

I do it two times and anticipate that the second time MongoDB will not add any new row since the data has been already added and there is an index on the `guid` field. But that's not the case MongoDB adds duplicates despite index value.

Why does MongoDB add duplicates even if there is an index on a `guid` and/or `guid.content` field? And how to fix it? I want to be able to add the document with the same `guid` field only one time.

Here is a sample of documents structure:
[image: Documents Schema Example]

In my data the `guid` field is a unique document identifier.

Comment: That is not true. Why do you think `ChinaPost-f411f6... === skynews-1a2346...`?

Comment: @user3100115, actually I mean that if I run the insert command two times or more then MongoDB will add `ChinaPost-f411f6…` twice or more. I'm not comparing `ChinaPost-f411f6…` with `skynews-1a2346…` but `ChinaPost-f411f6…` from the first execution with `ChinaPost-f411f6…` of the second execution  of insert and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [Phillip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1620671/philipp), I composed a completely worked solution for the problem «How to avoid duplicates / skip duplicates on insert» in ***MongoDB 3.2*** for ***Java Driver 3.2.0***:

```
    IndexOptions options = new IndexOptions();

    // ensure the index is unique
    options.unique(true);
    // define the index
    dbColl.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("guid", 1), options);

    // add data to DB
    for (Object item : itemsArr) {

        // if there is a duplicate, skip it and write to a console (optionally)
        try {
            dbColl.insertOne(Document.parse(item.toString()));
        } catch (com.mongodb.MongoWriteException ex) {
            //System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Feel free to use this ready-to-use solution.

Answer (score 4):

Regular indexes allow multiple documents with the same value.

What you need is not a regular index but [an unique index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/). These are created by using the method [`createIndex(DBObject keys, DBObject options)`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#createIndex-com.mongodb.DBObject-com.mongodb.DBObject-) with an options-object where `unique` is `true`.

```
collection.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("guid", 1), new BasicDBObject("unique", true));
```

Comment: Thanks Philip, could, you, please clarify, do I understand correctly that the approach `db.members.createIndex( { "user_id": 1 }, { unique: true } )` described here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/ is outdated?

Comment: @MikeB. it's not *outdated* this is how you create unique index.

Comment: @user3100115, so what's the difference between `db.members.createIndex( { "user_id": 1 }, { unique: true } )` and `db.members.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("user_id", 1), new BasicDBObject("unique", true));`? Is it absolutely the same? If both variants work, which of them should I use and when should I prefer one over another?

Comment: The first syntax is used in the shell while the second use the Java driver.

Comment: @MikeB. The first example is how you create an unique index in Javascript, the second how you do the exact same thing in Java. Because index creation is a one-time action you can of course set up your indexes with the MongoDB shell using Javascript, but I would recommend to do it in the Java application at startup, because it makes deployment easier. When the exact same index already exists, createIndex is a no-op.